# Why is it that $2\times 0 = 0$, but $2^0= 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Why is it that $2\times 0 = 0$, but $2^0= 1$?

I don't understand the reason behind it. If anyone explain it then it will be very appreciated. I know how multiplication, addition, and division work, but this one always puts my mind back to null.

Comment: Let $A$ be a set with two elements, and let $B=\emptyset$. Then $A\times B=\emptyset$ but there is one function $B\to A$.

Comment: means there is something between 0 to 2 ?

Comment: It's defined this way in the first place in order to make the laws of exponents work.  If $n^{a-b}  = n^a/n^b,$ what happens when $a=b?$  Then of course, it turns out to be convenient in a lot more contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\;2 \cdot 3 = \color{red}{0} + \underbrace{2 + 2 + 2}_{3\;\text{times}}\;$, while $\;2^3 = \color{red}{1} \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}_{3\;\text{times}}\;$.

Comment: According to your answer what is the value of 0 power 0 = ?

Comment: @user5355606 No particular value, since $\,0^0\,$ is undefined. You may find it *defined* as $\,0^0=1\,$ in *some* contexts, but that's just for convenience in those particular contexts, and does not follow from the addition and multiplication properties.

Comment: Thanks dxiv. As far as i understand we have to use 1 when we deal with powers ?

Comment: @user5355606 If you mean that $x^0=1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ then, yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for valid reason. My teacher answer was 'thats how math works'. But he didn't know maths is made by men not men made by maths.

Comment: @user5355606 Glad it helped. That said, don't judge your teacher too harshly, more often than not they simply don't have the time they'd wish they had to go into all the deeper pinnings. But keep your inquisitiveness up, once you are satisfied with the "*whys*" rather than just the "*whats*" those things tend to stick a lot better in memory going forward.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion dxiv.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively: $2\cdot0=2\cdot(1-1)=2-2=0$; $2^0=2^{1-1}=\frac22=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that for all reals $x$ and $y$ and positive $a$ the following is true.
$$a^{x-y}=\frac{a^x}{a^y}.$$
Now, let $x=y$.

We obtain $$a^0=1.$$